# How to implement Steamworks API into an existing macOS / Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, steamworks-api

I intend to submit an existing macOS game to Steam. It was made with Xcode using Objective-C and Swift.

According to the [Steamworks documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api) I need to link `libsteam_api.dylib` in the Xcode project.

However this does not seem to be enough. Several specific build and target settings need to be made, of which I can find no documentation. Also several other conditions need to be met, such as init calls that should be made.

The [non-C++ language support page](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api#thirdparty) unfortunately has no information about Objective-C / Swift / Xcode and searching the web does not return any useful information other than how to code sign Mac games for Steam.

Is there any tutorial / help / step by step guide on how to do make the game submittable to Steam?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Objective-C++ for easy integrate SteamWorks API to your Xcode project.
SteamWorks SDK has example named "steamworksexample" that show how to use it.